# How to get the max of different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having two tables like this:

LastDownloaded:

```
Movie    Date-last-downloaded
 A              1-1-1111
 B              2-2-2222
 C              3-3-3333
 D              4-4-4444
 E              5-5-5555
```

LastPurchased:

```
Movie    Date-last-purchased
 A              0-0-0000
 B              3-3-3333
 C              5-5-5555
 G              2-2-2222
 H              7-7-7777
```

and I'm trying to find the last download OR purchase of each movie. That is:

- If a movie is both purchased and downloaded, return whichever date is later (most recent)
- Otherwise, if it's only downloaded and not purchased (and vice-versa), return the `Date-last-downloaded` (or `Date-last-purchased`)

how can I do it?

The end result should be something like this:

```
Movie    Date-last-purchased-or-downloaded
 A              1-1-1111
 B              3-3-3333
 C              5-5-5555
 D              4-4-4444
 E              5-5-5555
 G              2-2-2222
 H              7-7-7777
```

(the question name is misleading - I would appreciate it if someone would think of a better one and fix it for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  movie
,       max(dt)
from    (
        select  Movie
        ,       Date-last-downloaded as dt
        from    LastDownloaded
        union all
        select  Movie
        ,       Date-last-purchased
        from    LastPurchased
        ) SubQueryAlias
group by
        movie
```

Comment: thanks, it works great! But can you please explain why you only set the alias `dt` for `Date-last-downloaded` and not `Date-last-purchased`? Will `Date-last-purchased` be labeled as `dt` by default since it comes after `Date-last-downloaded`?

Comment: A column can have only one nane.  The first query of a union determines the column names of the result set.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    coalesce(lp.movie, ld.movie) movie,
    greatest(
        date_last_downloaded,
        date_last_purchased
    ) Date_last_purchased_or_downloaded
from
    lastdownloaded ld
    full outer join
    lastpurchased lp on ld.movie = lp.movie
```